# Can I notify Bitbucket that build was aborted on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I would like Bitbucket to be notified when my build on Jenkins is aborted. Currently, such build is marked as failed. Is it possible to distinguish aborted from failed on Bitbucket?

I was looking at Bitbucket docs, but I cannot find anything useful.
I have tried Bitbucket Build Status Notifier Plugin, but it appears they consider aborted failed -> https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-build-status-notifier-plugin/blob/1.4.0/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/bitbucket/BitbucketBuildStatusHelper.java#L212-L213

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `post` section, you could have a section `aborted`.

```
post {
  aborted {
    // Notify BitBucket
  }
}
```

If you want the BitBucket build status to be something else, you can manipulate it within the `aborted` block using the BitBucket API ([doc](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-commit-statuses/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-commit-commit-statuses-get)).

This block from the docs show how you can force the commit to have a "successful" status:

```
curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/my-workspace/my-repo/commit/e10dae226959c2194f2b07b077c07762d93821cf/statuses/build/           -X POST -u jdoe -H 'Content-Type: application/json'           -d '{
    "key": "MY-BUILD",
    "state": "SUCCESSFUL",
    "description": "42 tests passed",
    "url": "https://www.example.org/my-build-result"
  }'
```

Comment: Can you suggest how to do this in Bitbucket Server? I am searching it's documentation, but I cannot find it.

Comment: @bkomo Try this: https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/docs/5.8.0/how-tos/updating-build-status-for-commits.html